# PHPExcel. не верная кодировка из html, стили не применяются

Tags: php, phpexcel

Сохраняю таблицу в формате xlsx

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
file_put_contents($path."/table.html", $html);
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML;
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($path."/table.html");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($path."/table.xlsx");
```

Файл создается, но вместо русских букв крякозябры.
В $html передается html-код со страницы браузера (utf-8).
Помогите победить кодировку.

С кодировкой вопрос решился.

Решение оказалось как всегда простым. Я пытался конвертировать html в эксель. Но в этом html был только код таблицы

```
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

а надо

```
<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body><table> .....................
```

Как теперь сохранить стили таблицы?

```
<td style='background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #000; width: 250px'>
```

не помогает

Comment: Попробуйте выбрать в икселе сменить кодировку сохранить файл и переоткрыть заново.

Comment: Так не пойдет. Файл формируется скриптом и сразу отправляется руководителю на почту.

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось как всегда простым.
Я пытался конвертировать html в эксель.
Но в этом html был только код таблицы

```
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

а надо

```
<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body><table> .....................
```

Comment: Красиво получилось наверное. Библиотека PhpExcel на самом деле очень выручает.

Comment: Да не очень. Стили таблицы не сохраняются :( Не знаю как победить.

Comment: стили должны находится в `<head>` насколько я понимаю, между `<style></style>`

Comment: или же попробовать вписать атрибут `style=""` в тэги, где нужны стили:  `<td style="color:grey"></td>` ручками, если даже так не работает может версию попробовать другую PHPEXcel?

Comment: @fonjeekay Всмысле другую PHPExcel?

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется что дело в `file_put_contents`

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
file_put_contents($path."/table.html", mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'OLD-ENCODING'));
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML;
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($path."/table.html");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($path."/table.xlsx");
```

[How to write file in UTF-8 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839402/how-to-write-file-in-utf-8-format)

Comment: Вот и я думаю что проблема в file_put_contents.
Но ваш пример не сработал

Comment: Но скорее всего дело не в этом. Записывал файл и в UTF-8 и windows-1251, а файл открывается с крякозябрами. Думаю что сама библиотека криво переводит Html в xlsx.

Comment: я с ней уже год работаю и тоже были приколы с кодировкой,

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй использовать функцию → `iconv()`.

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
$html = iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", $html);
file_put_contents($path."/table.html", $html);
```

Comment: От куда кп1251? За это и минус собственно

Comment: iconv не помогает